Powershell list one column above the other
Hi i would need to transform a table in a text file, delimiter is tab, with multiple columns into one single column, where col1 ist on top, col2 below, col3 below col2 and so, using powershell
Example:
data10 data20 data30
data11 data21 data31
data12 data22 data32

should turn into
data10
data11
data12
data20
data21
data22
data30
data31
data32

Output should be exported to a file.
Help would be much appreciated! :-)
Only method i could figure out ist, to list the data row by row, so to speak
data10
data20
data30
data11
data21

... but thats not what i need.

Sounds like it would do you well to look into the -split operator and Sort-Object cmdlet. Might be all you need without going a different route like ConvertFrom-Csv

You can simply split on variable amount of whitespace and then sort the results based on the number alone.
-split (Get-Content $csvfile) | Sort-Object {$_ -replace '\D+'}

-split will take care of all the whitespace, -replace '\D+' will remove all non digit characters.
output
data10
data11
data12
data20
data21
data22
data30
data31
data32

Now if this example doesn't cover situation where you still want to line up by column, then I would approach it like a CSV.
# provide headers and then extract the data from them.
$data = Import-Csv $csvfile -Delimiter "`t" -Header first, second, third
$data.first, $data.second, $data.third

Again the output is
data10
data11
data12
data20
data21
data22
data30
data31
data32


First, what happens if the data is not uniform?  The code below will read only those cells that exist, and this is the data used in this answer:
data10  data20  data30
data11  data21  data31  data41
data12  data22  data32

The goal here is to create an array of arrays.  Each line read by Get-Content becomes a row, and each line is split by the tab character and returned as an array of strings, with each cell belonging to a different column.
$Data = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\data.txt" | & {
   process {
      , ($_ -split "`t")
   }
}

Now we find out how long the longest row is:
$MaxLen = ($Data | &{process{$_.Length}} | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

Now we loop through each column, then sub loop through each row of $Data, return the Cells value only if $ColumnIndex is less than the length of the current row.
$Results = 0..($MaxLen - 1) | & {
   process {
      $ColumnIndex = $_
      $Data | & {
         process {
            if ($ColumnIndex -lt $_.Length) {
               $_[$ColumnIndex]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

And we finally send the results to a file:
$Results | Out-File -FilePath "$PSScriptRoot\dataOut.txt"

And this is the results in the dataOut.txt file.
data10
data11
data12
data20
data21
data22
data30
data31
data32
data41

As you can see, the extra data data41 was included by itself at the end of the file.

This solution is simplistic, but it would not depend on the sort order of the data. It presumes that each record contains the same, three (3), columns. With parameters and more code it could be able to handle a variable number of columns.
$CsvData = Import-Csv -Path .\so78498310.csv -Delimiter "`t" -Header a,b,c
$CsvData.a
$CsvData.b
$CsvData.c

